# Persistent HttpURLConnection in Java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, persistent

I am trying to write a java program that will automatically download and name some of my favorite web comics. Since I will be requesting multiple objects from the same domain, I wanted to have a persistent http connection that I could keep open until all the comics have been downloaded. Below is my work-in-progress. How do I make another request from the same domain but different path without opening a new http connection?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class ComicDownloader
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpc = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;

        try
        {
            url = new URL("http://www.cad-comic.com/cad/archive/2002");
            httpc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }

            input.close();
            httpc.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html), HTTP persistence is being handled transparently in Java, although it gives you the options to control it too via `http.keepAlive` and `http.maxConnections` system properties.

However,

> The current implementation doesn't
> buffer the response body. Which means
> that the application has to finish
> reading the response body or call
> close() to abandon the rest of the
> response body, in order for that
> connection to be reused. Furthermore,
> current implementation will not try
> block-reading when cleaning up the
> connection, meaning if the whole
> response body is not available, the
> connection will not be reused.

Take a look at the link and see if it really helps you.

Comment: link is dead? also does it still apply to newer versions of java?

Comment: @royerdpack Of course it does. You can't seriously believe they would take a valuable feature like this out.

Comment: @rogerdpack Use a Google search like this next time: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+api+doc+net%2Fhttp-keepalive.html Meanwhile am fixing the link.

Comment: Finish reading *and* do not call close() on the input stream or output stream. Calling close() caused my client code to re-open the HTTPS connection.

Comment: FWIW I think I read once https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767595/32453  that calling disconnect (like the OP does) also causes the Socket to not be re-used/cached...

Answer (score 5):

According to this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html, HTTP connection reuse is enabled by default, you can use Wireshark to check the interactions between your client and server. The first request contains TCP and SSL handshakes(if your request is https), the subsequent requests fired in the keep-alive time, contains no TCP and SSL handshakes, just application data transfers.

Answer (score 0):

Even though HttpURLConnection enable keep-alive by default, it is not guaranteed that HttpURLConnection uses same TCP connection for multiple HTTP requests. I faced same kind of issue when writing HTTPS client application. Solved this issue by using single instance of SSLContext, SSLSocketFactory and HttpsURLConnection.

```
public class MyHTTPClient {
    private SSLContext mSSLContext = null;
    private SSLSocketFactory mSSLSocketFactory = null;
    private HttpsURLConnection mConnection = null;

    public void init() {
        //Setup SSL context and Socket factory here
    }

    pubblic void sendRequest() {
        URL url = new URL("https://example.com/request_receiver");
        mConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        mConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(mSSLSocketFactory);

        // Setup request property and send request
        // Open input stream to read response
        // Close output, input streams
        
        mConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```