# Java URL / HttpURLConnection how to avoid InputStream while posting?

Tags: java, url, http-post, httpurlconnection

Is it possible to do a POST method request to some URL and avoid reading the response?

No matter how hard I try to avoid reading the response the data never seems to reach the server unless I read the response.. strange?

I really have no point in reading any response data as all I will be doing is posting data.. (the response will always be blank anyways)

```
 URL postURL = new URL("http://www.example.com/test/");
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) postURL.openConnection();
 con.setUseCaches(false);
 con.setDoOutput(true);
 con.setDoInput(false); //why even make this if it doesn't function?
 con.setRequestMethod("POST"); 

 //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(con.getOutputStream());
 OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
 byte[] /*String postStr*/ bPost = ("foo1="+URLEncoder.encode("bar1")+"&"+  
                       "foo2="+URLEncoder.encode("bar2")+"&"+   
                       "foo3="+URLEncoder.encode("bar3").getBytes();
 out.write(bPost);

 //out.println(postStr); // send to server
 out.flush();
 out.close();   // close outputstream
 //con.getInputStream().close(); //thought maybe this would help but no change.


 /*
 //If I uncomment this it will work.
 String inputLine="";   //Stores the line of text returned by the server
 String resultsPage=""; // Stores the complete HTML results page

 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
       resultsPage+=inputLine;
 in.close();
 */
```

Comment: Related: [Safe use of HttpURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767553)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `getResponseCode()` after the writes.

This will also give you 404 as a response code rather than `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: getInputStream() is called in getResponseCode()

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried calling `con.connect()`?

Otherwise it will probably do that "lazily" when it absolutely has to (POST buffer full, starting to read the response headers, etc).

Comment: where do I put con.connect()? before i write? is there any bad side effects? .. i call flush and hopefully inputStream is disabled? it shouldn't fill that up. or?, btw this isn't a keep-alive connection it's just a simple post to a url..

Comment: connect() doesn't accelerate anything.