# How to gracefully clean up an HTTPURLConnection when an exception is caught?

Tags: java, exception, applet, httpurlconnection

I have a Java applet that uses the `HTTPURLConnection` class to upload very large files to an IIS-7 web-server. The applet chunks the files into pieces, then POSTs the pieces using fixed-length streaming to a PHP script.

Occasionally, when uploading file chunks, the network connection between the client and the server mysteriously drops. When this happens, my call to the `writeBytes()` method throws an `IOException` which I catch. After catching this exception, I drop down into my `finally` block where I try to clean things up. Because insufficient data was written to the connection (remember, this is fixed-length streaming), **the attempt to close the output stream also fails**. As a result, the connection seemingly "sticks around" (i.e. the underlying socket remains open). This seems to be verified by looking at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.html#close) to the `close()` method for the StreamingOutputStream class (note the comment stating that the socket cannot be closed).

### Question:

Is there a graceful way I can shut down after catching an `IOException` while writing out to an `HTTPURLConnection`? Telling the `HTTPURLConnection` object to `disconnect()` doesn't seem to be good enough.

### Additional info:

Here's the first exception I see when the network gets hosed, thrown by my call to the `writeBytes()` method of the `HTTPURLConnection` class:

```
java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at MultiPartPostThread.run(MultiPartPostThread.java:321)
```

I catch this exception, and then attempt to close the `DataOutputStream` object that I was using to write to the connection. When I do so, I get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at MultiPartPostThread.run(MultiPartPostThread.java:370)
```

I can verify that the socket is staying open, by noting that it takes 10 minutes for the failure entry to show up in the IIS log. That delay (10 minutes) happens to be my connection timeout value. Example lines from the IIS log (trimmed for brevity):

```
2012-01-31 20:20:07 POST /upload_handler.php 200 0 0 356 26215490 3666
2012-01-31 20:20:10 POST /upload_handler.php 200 0 0 356 26215490 3853
2012-01-31 20:30:22 POST /upload_handler.php 500 0 64 0 15286099 611442
```

Note that in the first two lines of the log we're transferring along nicely: 25 MB is sent each time, and a 200 status code is returned. The failure then shows up 10 minutes after the last successful transfer, with an unhelpful error 500 (and note that this was only a partial transfer; only ~15MB transferred). In actuality, this mysterious disconnect occurs about 1 minute into the whole procedure, so the timeout messages I'm seeing in my IIS trace logs are red herrings. I see nothing helpful in my PHP logs, the HTTPERR log, or in the system log on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more I look into this, the more I'm convinced that a graceful cleanup cannot take place. A `disconnect()` call doesn't seem to be enough to close the underlying socket; you simply have to wait for it to time out.

I think I'll try using the [Apache HttpComponents HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) (as recommended at the bottom of this [terrific SO wiki post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)), to see if its built-in error handling can take care of this bizarre case I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `close()` on your stream should release the resources used by

```
HTTPURLConnection
```

Here is note from HTTPURLConnection javadoc

Calling the close() methods on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection after a request may free network resources associated with this instance but has no effect on any shared persistent connection. Calling the disconnect() method may close the underlying socket if a persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.

Comment: The problem is that the `close()` call itself throws an exception (i.e. it doesn't succeed). This is in addition to the IOException thrown by the write.

Comment: Then only option is disconnect(). You may check this interesting SO discusssion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767553/safe-use-of-httpurlconnection

Comment: I call disconnect as a part of my ultimate clean-up. That doesn't seem to do the trick. It may be that I don't have the appropriate access to the bowels of this class to fix this issue...