# Java close both Connection and InputStream with try statement

Tags: java, stream, try-catch, inputstream, try-with-resources

Should I close HttpUrlConnection and InputStream in this case? Only closing the connection will close the stream also? I feel that it's a bad practice but don't know exactly why.

Closing both:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
try (AutoCloseable ac = con::disconnect) {
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    try (InputStream ins = responseCode >= 400 ? con.getErrorStream() : con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins))) {
        // receive response
    }
}
```

Closing Connection only:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
try (AutoCloseable ac = con::disconnect) {
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins)))
    // ins will close automatically when con closes?
    // receive response
}
```

Comment: if uncle Bob know that you nest exception handling code he will find you :) do not say i did not worn you :)))) and i see  Volodya Lombrozo  explain it well

Comment: @justsomeone this code I got from another thread. In real life I made connection and input stream resources at the same try statement. Will I stay alive?

Comment: loool you fine and this uncle bob video for clean code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EmboKQH8lM&t=5811s and in my humble opinion everyone should learn about clean code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you disconnect the `HttpURLConnection` object, it **MAY** also close any `InputStream` or `OutputStream` that it has opened.

`HttpURLConnection.disconnect()` method description:

> Calling the disconnect() method **may** close the underlying socket if a persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.

You can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect--).

In turn, `Socket.close()` method description:

> Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream.
> If this socket has an associated channel then the channel is closed as well.

You can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()).

But pay attention that "disconnecting" `HttpURLConnection` doesn’t mandatory close the `Socket`.
It have been already discussed quite well in that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767553/safe-use-of-httpurlconnection):

> (When `keepAlive == true`)
> If client called `HttpURLConnection.getInputSteam().close()`, the later call to `HttpURLConnection.disconnect()` will **NOT** close the `Socket`. i.e. The `Socket` is reused (cached)
> If client does not call `close()`, call `disconnect()` will close the `InputStream` and close the `Socket`.
> So in order to reuse the `Socket`, just call `InputStream.close()`. Do not call `HttpURLConnection.disconnect()`.

On the other hand, in the [official oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) they suggest to close `InputStream` explicitly in order to be sure that resources don’t leak.