# How does URLConnection in java reuses the connection from the pool

Tags: java

Can any one help me with a sample code of how the URLConnection reuses the connection?

```
URLConnection con = new URL("http://www.someurl.com").openConnection();
```

I am using the above code to make a URLConnection. For the first time, the URLConnection will open a new connection to the specified URL. But after that it will reuse the existing connection from the pool. Is there any to prove this (I mean through println()) ?

Actually is there any way to retrieve connection reused status from the pool?

Comment: You might be able to "wire sniff" to confirm that it's actually re-using connections.  Or check the connection at the server (assuming it uses http keep-alives, that's the only case when it reuses connections I'd imagine...) See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3304006/32453

Answer (score 4):

From the `java.net.URL` javadoc:

> Returns a URLConnection object that represents a connection to the
>   remote object referred to by the URL.
>
> **A new connection is opened every time** by calling the openConnection
>   method of the protocol handler for this URL.
>
> If for the URL's protocol (such as HTTP or JAR), there exists a
>   public, specialized URLConnection subclass belonging to one of the
>   following packages or one of their subpackages: java.lang, java.io,
>   java.util, java.net, the connection returned will be of that subclass.
>   **For example, for HTTP an HttpURLConnection will be returned**, and for
>   JAR a JarURLConnection will be returned.

So for a http protocol url it will return a `HttpURLConnection`

From the `java.net.HttpURLConnection` javadoc:

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request **but the
>   underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be transparently shared by other instances**

So the underlining tcp connection might be pooled

Comment: Okay. Agreed. But is it possible to prove it? It would be very much helpful if you provide a sample code to prove the tcp connection being pooled and reused.

Comment: @Dilip B S It isn't possible to prove it from code, that's how completely it's engineered to be hidden under the hood. You would have to sniff the network.

Comment: hmmm:) But it seems just conceptual. So perhaps there could be a way to prove it... We rely on the java doc. If the requirement is to prove it, then we have to.

Comment: hmm having to prove that a programming language base library does what is says is a little strange. Is it more related to having to profile a certain method for network traffic?

Comment: :-)   But my requirement is that... Anyway thanks for the response