# how does keep alive work httpurlconnection java

Tags: java, http, networking

What does setting the connection header to keep alive do. I'm noticing, setting it to close makes a faster connection than keep alive by approx. 150 ms on average, when reading the html content on a given site. Why? Why do browsers generally send keep alive headers?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive

Comment: whats the point of a browser sending it, and how would java make use of it in an httpurlconnection?

Comment: See the link forwarding to HTTP persistent connections: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304006/persistent-httpurlconnection-in-java

Comment: google chrome visits google.com, sending keep alive header. Now the user cliks news at the top. what did that keep alive do? Also, java keep alive header is set, and connection opened to http://www.google.com, then the connection is not closed. how would you visit google.com?q=oiu on the same connection?