# Creation of url connection pool in java

Tags: java, connection, pool

I have some code like this in a method :

```
        URL url = new URL(endPoint);
        String encoding = Base64.encodeBase64String(this.key.getBytes());

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

This method is called many times from the client side. I wish I could create a connection pool and reuse the same as needed.

Is it possible to do so in Java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304006/persistent-httpurlconnection-in-java

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html this may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pooling HTTP connection is similar to other pooling object.

Basically :

- use a factory to get an instance of your HTTP connections
- dont forget to release it, via the factory, to your pool when no more used
- in your pool management don't forget to check and close your connections.

I don't advise you to re-code all pool management, but rather use existing librairies like
Jakarta Commons-pool.

Jakarta Commons-pool enable you :

- to reject immediatly demand of new HTTP connection with a "pool exhausted exception"
- to increase pool size despite his limits
- to wait during N ms, expecting a free HTTP connection (exception after delay).

Comment: thanks.. are there any code examples for Jakarta Commons-pool to pool the url connections?