# Connection close in Java Servlet and SSE

Tags: java, servlets, server-sent-events

I try to implement Server-Sent-Event in my Webapp with Java Serlvet on server.

Is it possible to check in Servlet that connection is closed by client? The loop `while(true)` in Servlet is infinite even if client browser is closed.

**Client code**

```
    function startLogSSE(lastEventId, level) {
        var eventSource = new EventSource("log-sse?last-event-id=" + lastEventId + "&level=" + level);
        eventSource.onmessage = function (event) {
            document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = event.data + "\n" + document.getElementById('log').innerHTML;
        };
    }
```

**Server code**

```
public class LogSSEServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogSSEServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        // get logger purgerDB appender
        PurgerDBAppender appender = LogUtils.getPurgerDBAppender();
        if (appender == null) {
            writer.write("data: [ERROR] Appender 'purgerDB' isn't found for logger 'com.bp3'\n\n");
            writer.close();
            return;
        }

        int eventId = 0;
        // get last-event-id
        String lastEventId = request.getHeader("last-event-id");
        if (lastEventId == null) {
            // try to get lastEventId from parameter
            lastEventId = request.getParameter("last-event-id");
        }
        if (lastEventId != null) {
            try {
                eventId = Integer.parseInt(lastEventId);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                logger.error("Failed to parse last-event-id: " + lastEventId);
            }
        }
        String minLevel = request.getParameter("level");
        if (minLevel == null) {
            minLevel = "TRACE";
        }

        // get logs from purgerDB logger appender
        LogServices logServices = new LogServices();
        try {
            logServices.open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
        try {
            while (true) {
                List<LogMessage> messages = logServices.getLastMessages(Level.toLevel(minLevel), eventId, 0);
                if (messages.size() > 0) {
                    writer.write("id: " + messages.get(0).getEventId() + "\n");
                    writer.write("data: " + LogUtils.formatLog(messages) + "\n");
                    writer.flush();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        } finally {
            logServices.closeQuietly();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to me like you're trying to reimplement WebSockets. Or Comet.

Comment: Do some googling on 'persistent connections' if you're trying to keep it open, otherwise by default I believe the connection should be closed once all data has been transmitted by the server.
For creating a persistent connection see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304006/persistent-httpurlconnection-in-java

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to check in Servlet that connection is closed by client?

Eventually an exception will be thrown: either an `IOException: connection reset` if you are streaming directly to the socket, or an `OutOfMemoryError` if the container is streaming to memory, which it does when you aren't using a fixed-length or chunked transfer mode.

> The loop while(true) in Servlet is infinite even if client browser is closed.

No it isn't.

Comment: Yes, it is :). No exception is thrown. I also expected it.
Application server used: WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile

Comment: hi, @sasha_trn, could you share with us your conclusions on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ricardo, It was a long time ago. AFAIR, I didn't find a way to determine connection closing by client. I changed my code without the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, @sasha_trn, from `HttpServlet`, `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` [source codes](http://grepcode.com/), I see no mention to connection, and also I get no `Exception`. Best,

Answer (score 0):

One way to check, wihin the `Servlet`, that connection is closed, is using the `writer.checkError()` method. I tested this fix on Chrome and it works. Your code would be:

```
            boolean error=false;
            while (!error) {
                //...                   
                writer.write("data: " + /*...*/  "\n");
                //writer.flush();
                error = writer.checkError();    //internally calls writer.flush()
            }
```

**Details**:

The [`PrintWriter`'s API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) says:

> Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions, although some of its
>   constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have
>   occurred by invoking `checkError()`.

and the [checkError()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError()) says:

> Flushes the stream if it's not closed and checks its error state

Comment: Credits to my friends Shuge Li and Enyong Chen, not yet in this community.